# How to loop user input in Java

Tags: java

So far, my code looks like this:

```
    package kittensworld;

    import java.util.Scanner;

    public class KittensWorld {
        public static void main(String[] args){

            System.out.println("What is the first kitten's name?");
            Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
            String kitten1 = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("What is the second kitten's name?");
            String kitten2 = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("And the third kiten's name?");
            String kitten3 = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("The first kitten's name is " + kitten1);
            System.out.println("The second kitten is " + kitten2);
            System.out.println("And last but not least, " + kitten3);
        }
    }
```

How would I go about looping it so that I can ask for the names of 20 kittens, without copying and pasting it 20 times?

Comment: Just use a loop. What else are you looking for?

Comment: make an array of `String`:  `String[] kittens = new String[20]`

Comment: There are two possible scenarios:

Number One is to use arrays where each items is held as a string and you loop 20 times.

Number Two is to use an ARRAY LIST where each list item holds the name of each kitten whilst you loop 20 times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`for`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) loop and [array](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html) that'll contain the data:

```
String[] inputs = new String[NUMBER_OF_INPUTS];
Scanner scanner = new Scanner();
for(i=0; i<NUMBER_OF_INPUTS; i++) {
   inputs[i] = scanner.nextLine();
}
```

If you don't know the number of inputs (but you know what symbol will represent the end of the input), you can use a [`while`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) loop and an [`ArrayList`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html).

Answer (score 2):

I think you need to look up this tutorial about this proper loop called [**`for-loop`**](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html):

```
String[] kitten = new String [size];
for(int i = 0 ; i < kitten.length; i++){
 System.out.println("kitten number "+i+" : ");
 kitten [i] = scan.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Now it's good :) It's better to loop until `size` instead of doing `kitten.length`.. You already have the size.

Comment: If you don't want to confuse other people replace `String []kitten` with `String[] kitten` because `[]` is part of the type, not the name.

Answer (score 1):

```
package kittensworld;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class KittensWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        for (int i = 0; i < 20; i++){
            System.out.println("What is the kitten's name?");
            String kitten = scan.nextLine();
            System.out.println("That kitten's name was " + kitten);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
package kittensworld;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class KittensWorld {

    private static final int NUMBER_OF_KITTENS = 20;
    public static void main(String[] args){
        String[] kittenNames = new int[NUMBER_OF_KITTENS];
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);

        for(int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_KITTENS; ++i)
        {
            System.out.println("What is the name of kitten number " + (i+1) + "?");
            kittenNames[i] = scan.nextLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    ArrayList<String> kittenNames = new ArrayList<>();
    int number = 3 ; // number of kitten names ( +1 )

    for (int i = 1; i < number; i++) {
        System.out.printf("What is the %s kitten's name?\n", ordinal(i));
        kittenNames.add(scan.nextLine());
    }
    System.out.println("===============================================");
    for (String name : kittenNames) {
        System.out.println(name);
    }
}

public static String ordinal(int i) {
    String[] sufixes = new String[]{"th", "st", "nd", "rd", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th", "th"};
    switch (i % 100) {
        case 11:
        case 12:
        case 13:
            return i + "th";
        default:
            return i + sufixes[i % 10];

    }
}
```